# Cordova Error when a loaded page launch a 3rd party app

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I have a Cordova app that launches a page/url on an InAppBrowser.  The page works perfectly from the phone's browser. It allows users to order and pay online.  It also perfectly launches the bank's app installed on the device when bank payment is chosen.

However, when I launch the same pages on an InAppBrowser inside my Cordova App, the browser throws an error - UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.  It won't open the bank's app installed.  Anyone knows how to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance!

--edited added image

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqZr9.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wTMI.png)

Added the source code and the screenshot of the error.  The page should open a bank's app/page, and is using the stripe platform.  Hoping anyone would have an idea.  Thanks!

Comment: can you include the code, it clearly tells that the in app browser can't find the url or it's url scheme is unknown so url scheme is the first clue.

Comment: Thanks Osaf!  I just load a URL  that has a button on it.  This button loads the app. I don't have access to that page's source code.  However, when I load the URL on the phone's browser, it works perfectly!

Comment: you have to check the url scheme it's really hard to find problem without any code you know

Comment: Understood.  Added the screenshot.  I pass on the URL that loads the page that has the button on it.